# QAbstractTableModel and QSortFilterProxyModel - how to clear data and update view

Tags: c++, qt, model, pyqt, pyside

Given a `QSortFilterProxyModel` and a `QAbstractTableModel` with the proxy set to the table model and that proxy used in a `QTableView` how would I

- clear the actual data
- update the view to show the change in data

Pseudo-code:

```
class MyTableModel(QAbstractTabelModel):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        QAbstractTabelModel.__init__(self, parent)
  
        self.entries = [ <data entries here> ]

    @Slot()
    def slot_clear_entries(self):
        self.entries.clear()
        # Trigger refresh of model and notify all connected views
        pass

    # data(), headerData() etc.
    # ...

class MyProxyModel(QSortFilterProxyModel):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        QSortFilterProxyModel.__init__(self, parent)


class MyTableView(QTableView):
    def __init__(self, parent=None)
        QTableView.__init__(self, parent)


        self.model = MyTableModel()
        self.proxy = MyProxyModel()
        self.proxy.setSourceModel(self.model)
        self.setModel(self.proxy)
```

I'm using PySide above but have no problem with PyQt or pure Qt C++ solutions. I can replace the model but I am also considering a case where the model is also interacting with either a file or a database so I would like to handle a scenario where cleanup may involve extra steps.

Answer (score 0):

Found a nice example [here](https://github.com/pyside/Examples/blob/master/examples/itemviews/addressbook/tablemodel.py). Based on it I was able to override the following inside `MyTableModel` and add a slot that triggers removing all entries:

```
def removeRows(self, row, count, parent=QModelIndex(), *args, **kwargs):
    self.beginRemoveRows(parent, row, row+count-1)
    print(row, count)
    del self.entries[row:row+count]
    self.endRemoveRows()
    return True

@Slot()
def slot_clear_entries(self):
    self.removeRows(0, len(self.entries))
```

Comment: Note that you shouldn't use `removeRows` if you want to completely clear the contents, instead use [`beginResetModel()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qabstractitemmodel.html#beginResetModel) before clearing the entries and then [`endResetModel()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qabstractitemmodel.html#endResetModel).